# Como poner un link en tabla de jquery que abra un pdf usando generic handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

buenos dias:
tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
generic handler

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
  string nombreArchivo,tipo;
 //   int id = 12725; NOTA:"Si hago asi no marca error y si me muestra el pdf"
    int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);

     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myconsql))
    { 
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {   
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nomb, ruta, tipo FROM Cat WHERE id=@Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Connection = con; 
            con.Open(); 
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {   
                sdr.Read();
                ruta = (byte[])sdr["ruta"];
                tipo = sdr["tipo"].ToString();
                nombArchivo = sdr["nombArchivo"].ToString();
            } 
            con.Close();
        } 
    } 
    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.Charset = "";
    if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
    {
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombArchivo);
    }    
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(ruta);
    context.Response.Flush(); 
    context.Response.End();

}
public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {

        return false;
    }
```

marca este error:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: String Line 23:
>   int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);

Asi lo tengo en source asp.net  c#:

```
table.append("<tr id='row_" + i + "'><td name='id'>" + Data[i].id + "</td> +  " 
"<td style='display: none'>" + Data[i].ruta + "</td>" + " <td style='display: none'>" + Data[i].tipo + "</td>" + "<td name='nombArchivo'>" + "   <a href='http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?Id='" + Data[i].id +  "target='_blank='_blank'>" + Data[i].nombArchivo + "</a></td></td></tr>");
```

y cuando lo corro me sale ese error, mas sin en cambio si le asigno un id especifico en generic si me lo muestra, estare haciendo algo mal en source de la tabla html?????

Comment: "<td name='nombArchivo'>" + "<a href='http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id='" + Data[i].id + "target='_blank='_blank'>" + Data[i].nombArchivo + "</a></td></td></tr>"); alguien sabe si estoy escribiendo bien este codigo para que funcione mi generic handler???

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza:

```
<a href='http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?Id='" + Data[i].id +  "target='_blank='_blank'>"
```

Por:

```
<a href='http://localhost:25429/FileCS.ashx?id='" + Data[i].id +  " target='_blank'>"
```

Antes del target debe haber un espacio en blanco para que funcione como se espera, además hay otro "_blank" extra.

Comment: si lo pongo asi en la columna de la tabla no me muestra ni los id esta en blanco y ni en link muestra nada

Comment: vamos al chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41536/discussion-on-answer-by-fredyfx-como-poner-en-mi-tabla-en-json-jquery-un-pdf-de